# Javascript & problems

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following code:

```
var artist = document.getElementById("txtBoxArtist").value;
```

When value is plain text, e.g. Biffy Clyro, artist = Biffy Clyro

When value contains `&amp;`, e.g. Mumford `&` Sons, artist = Mumford

I the send artist value using AJAX, and recover the value on another php page like this:

```
var data = "nameTitle=" + title + "&nameArtist=" + artist;
```

[...]

```
$nameArtist=$_POST['nameArtist'];
```

Why does this happen and how to avoid it? It is giving me lots of problems this `&`symbol...

Thank you all!

Comment: Try use `textarea` instead of `input`

Comment: Wooot, the value property is always a string, it's not encoded with entities, so that's not possible?

Comment: Your problem might be unclear. Can you reproduce it in a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com) ? And describe it in more detail. Where is PHP involved for example ?

Comment: Hi, I can try to create a fiddle, but I don´t think it is easy....

Comment: @hindmost I have to use input, thanks.

Comment: It's because you're building the GET string manually, so the `&amp;` in the text actually splits the values (`&` by itself is a URL property delimiter). Your URL, in other words, looks like this: `/example.com/test.php?nametitle=whatever&nameArtist=Mumford+&amp;+Sons`

Comment: @dystroy I have added a bit more information! Thanks

Comment: How about I create a fiddle for you -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Qu6LU/

Comment: @JaredFarrish And how can I solve that? Sorry, but I have basic knowledge... Learning little by little!

Comment: @qalbiol - Always encode your URL components (individually, not the whole URL at once).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can encode valiables before sending them like this:

```
 artist = encodeURIComponent(artist);
 title = encodeURIComponent(title);
 var data = "nameTitle=" + title + "&nameArtist=" + artist;
```

hope this helps.

Comment: No it shouldn't, that's *explicitly* the problem. `encodeURIComponent()` is correct.

Comment: The 'C' in component needs to be capitalized: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: @naota Ok, this partially works, but result is then Mumford%20&%20Sons, which is not what I want, because when I then compare this value to the DB, of course it does not find it because of %20...

Comment: @bjb568 - One of my `shift` keys appears to be sticking.

Comment: @naota Solved it using urldecode() in PHP file. Thanks all, regards.

Comment: @qalbiol,Thank you. I'm grad it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the values before sticking them on the URL.

```
var data = "nameTitle=" + encodeURIComponent(title) + "&nameArtist=" + encodeURIComponent(artist);
```

You should also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent).

Comment: Note that `encodeURIComponent`) is correct (not `encodeURI`): *Note that **encodeURI by itself cannot form proper HTTP GET and POST requests**, such as for XMLHTTPRequests, **because "&", "+", and "=" are not encoded**, which are treated as special characters in GET and POST requests. encodeURIComponent, however, does encode these characters.* [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

Answer (score 1):

Some characters are special and need 'escaping' to encode their values - as you are showing using `&amp;` instead of `&`.

However, these escaping principles are different for HTML content and for URLs/URIs.

In URI, `&` is escaped as `%26` and not as `&amp;` - so you should either use that or the appropriate encoding/decoding functions, not the HTML entity encoding/decoding.